# Why is my code producing different values for the same code

Tags: c++, stm32

I'm working on a STM32L072 and have been creating a `timeLimit` class which job it is to track the amount of time that has passed and if it has gone over the set time. If the required time has elapsed the class will return this so time dependent code can be executed. This class uses ticks internally and as such the function `HW_RTC_Tick2ms` is used to convert back to ms. This function is provided by ST in their I-CUBE-LRWAN Expansion Package of which I'm using v1.2.1.

I have written the `printTimeToSend` function for logging/debugging and monitoring reasons. The original form prints out the current amount of elapsed time, the amount of time set to be waited and how much time until the next timeout.

The problem is that this code returns `134318771` when used in the original manner. I have split all the separate steps into variables and printed these out to trace where the conversion went wrong. BUT, it returns the correct results when split into separate steps.

*`PPRINTF` is a `printf` variant supplied by ST and is blocking. It uses a circulair buffer internally and has the same syntax for parameter passing.*

*The `__nop()` operations have been inserted for debugging. I use Keil for development and the stackviewer has trouble with updating variables sometimes in C++. As such the `__nop()` are a precaution to make sure the value is updated and visible before executing the next bit of relevant code*

*`HW_RTC_GetTimerValue` get the current time value in ticks.*

```
/** @author Tarick Welling
 * @brief outputs the current time, timeout time and time to transmission.
 */
void timeLimit::printTimeToSend() const {
  PPRINTF("%s\r\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
  auto now = HW_RTC_GetTimerValue();
  PPRINTF("now: %i\r\n", now);
  PPRINTF("now: %i\r\n",HW_RTC_Tick2ms(now));
  __nop();
  __nop();
  auto then = startTime;
  PPRINTF("then: %i\r\n", then);
  PPRINTF("then: %i\r\n",HW_RTC_Tick2ms(then));
  __nop();
  __nop();
  auto between = sendDelayTime;
  PPRINTF("between: %i\r\n", between);
  PPRINTF("between: %i\r\n",HW_RTC_Tick2ms(between));
  __nop();
  __nop();
  auto diff = (now - then);
  PPRINTF("diff: %i\r\n", diff);
  PPRINTF("diff: %i\r\n",HW_RTC_Tick2ms(diff));
  __nop();
  __nop();
  PPRINTF("bigger: %i\r\n", between < diff);
  PPRINTF("bigger: %i\r\n",HW_RTC_Tick2ms(between) < HW_RTC_Tick2ms(diff));

  PPRINTF("SEMI\r\n");
  auto subdiv = now - then;
  PPRINTF("\t current time: %i\r\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
          HW_RTC_Tick2ms(subdiv));
  PPRINTF("\t timeout time: %i\r\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
          HW_RTC_Tick2ms(between));
  PPRINTF("\t time to send: %i\r\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
          HW_RTC_Tick2ms(between - subdiv));

  PPRINTF("ORI\r\n");
  PPRINTF("\t current time: %i\r\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
          HW_RTC_Tick2ms(HW_RTC_GetTimerValue() - startTime));
  PPRINTF("\t timeout time: %i\r\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
          HW_RTC_Tick2ms(sendDelayTime));
  PPRINTF("\t time to send: %i\r\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
          HW_RTC_Tick2ms(sendDelayTime - (HW_RTC_GetTimerValue() - startTime)));
}
```

Output:

> ```
> void timeLimit::printTimeToSend() const
> now: 9702
> now: 9474
> then: 837
> then: 817
> between: 7372
> between: 7199
> diff: 8865
> diff: 8657
> bigger: 1
> bigger: 1
> SEMI
>          current time: 134318771
>          timeout time: 134318771
>          time to send: 134318771
> ORI
>          current time: 134318771
>          timeout time: 134318771
>          time to send: 134318771
> ```

```
TimerTime_t HW_RTC_Tick2ms(uint32_t tick) {
  uint32_t seconds = tick >> 0x0A;
  tick = tick & 0x03FF;
  return ((seconds * 1000) + ((tick * 1000) >> 0x0A));
}
```

I'm not able to reason my way from `134318771` which is `0x8018AB3` and `1000000000011000101010110011` be it bit flipped, shifted or otherwise modified in place to the original values.

The architecture of the system is 32 bits and as such the should be more than enough space for all the values which is confirmed in the demonstration of the concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your print calls at the end of your function look like this.

```
PPRINTF("\t current time: %i\r\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
          HW_RTC_Tick2ms(subdiv));
```

You want to format an integer but you provide a C-string and an integer.
`134318771` is probably the decimal representation of the address of the C-string `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

You need to make the format and the parameters match.

```
PPRINTF("\t current time: %i\r\n", HW_RTC_Tick2ms(subdiv));
```

or

```
PPRINTF("\t %s current time: %i\r\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
          HW_RTC_Tick2ms(subdiv));
```

Comment: @TarickWelling ;^) yes, it's so frustrating. Sometimes we just need to look at something else and when we come back to the problem it looks obvious...

Comment: Most stupid thing is that I've been comparing the assembly and I just totally overlooked the extra parameter being passed. ``BL HW_RTC_Tick2ms
MOV      r1,r0
ADR      r0,|L6.432|
BL       TraceSend``

Comment: @TarickWelling Were there no compiler warnings for the `printf`s ?

Comment: The `PPRINTF` (so not a real `stdlib.h` `printf`) is implemented using `__VA_ARGS__` and it just ignored the third argument. So no warnings